# Position HTML elements diagonally

Tags: javascript, html, positioning

I am new to Javascript & relatively new to HTML. I would like to know what language(pure html or Javascript & html) I should use & some suggestions of an algorithm in order to do the following:

Place 4 squares on a background but position them diagonally. Each square is a link you can click to go to a different page. **So how would I be able to position html  elements diagonally like my picture below?**

http://i54.tinypic.com/2v7uw5u.png

I believe my code would look like this:

```
<script>
    function positionIt()
    {
        var screenW = // javascript function to get screen width??;
        var screenH = // javascript function to get screen height??;

        var sq1 = document.getElementById( "square1" );
        var sq2 = document.getElementById( "square2" );
        var sq3 = document.getElementById( "square3" );
        var sq4 = document.getElementById( "square4" );

        // What javascript functions set a elements x,y positions?
        // Should I use another way of positioning the square (not by absolute terms)
        sq1.setXPos( screenW / 4 );
        sq1.setYPos( screenH / 4 );

        sq2.setXPos( screenW / 3 );
        sq2.setYPos( screenH / 3 );
    }
</script>

// OR if I use css
.menu { background-color: blue; }
/* Position the square in absolute terms diagonally */
#square1 { x=200; y=200; }
#square2 { x=300; y=300; }
#square3 { x=400; y=400; }
#square4 { x=500; y=500; }

<div class="menu" onload="positionIt()">
    <a id="square1" href="home.html"><img src="square.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="square2" href="home.html"><img src="square.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="square3" href="home.html"><img src="square.jpg" /></a>
    <a id="square4" href="home.html"><img src="square.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/PyA5s/)
[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/PyA5s/1/) (with `left` properties order changed to match your mockup)

I tried to keep to the numbers you asked for.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a id="square1" href="home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f90/fff" /></a>
    <a id="square2" href="home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f90/fff" /></a>
    <a id="square3" href="home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f90/fff" /></a>
    <a id="square4" href="home.html"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f90/fff" /></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    background: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative
}
/* Position the square in absolute terms diagonally */
#square1 { position:absolute; left:200px; top:200px; }
#square2 { position:absolute; left:300px; top:300px; }
#square3 { position:absolute; left:400px; top:400px; }
#square4 { position:absolute; left:500px; top:500px; }
```

How does this work? See: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Is there a way to get the screen/browser dimensions in css so I can use an expression like this: left: expression(screen.width <= 1000 ? screen.width/4: true)

Comment: @Mack: Not using CSS (yes with JS), but it would be better if I changed my demo to a `%` based layout instead if you want to compensate for different sized screens.

Comment: @Mack: Actually, I'm not sure what you want. Could you explain the relationship between the size of the screen, and what should change on the page? (size of boxes, position of boxes, etc)

Comment: @thritydot, the blue square (that the links will be in) will be a different width according to the screen width. But I am starting to think that using CSS & % to space it out should componsate for screen widths right?

Comment: @Mack: Yes, it should. Is this supposed to fill the whole page, or is it just supposed to be just one section of the page? (the menu?) I'm asking because it might be annoying to change it if I do it the wrong way for you.

Comment: @thirtydot, it will be part of a section. The page is divided into 3 columns, this will be in the middle column, the content column :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use absolute positioning for this purpose.

In CSS:

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: /*enough width for all of the positioned elements*/
    height: /*enough height for all of the position elements*/
}
#squareN {
    top: /*how far from top of #menu*/
    left: /*how far from left of #menu*/
    position: absolute;
    width: /*as required*/
    height: /*as required*/
}
```